# Laravel Method Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::test does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, phpmailer

In my laravel project i use mailgun and guzzlehttp/guzzle. My route code is

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
    $data = [
      'title'=>'Hellow Avijit',
      'content'=>'This is a testing of mailing in Laravel using mailgun'
    ];

    Mail::test('emails.test', $data, function($message) {
        $message->to('019129avijit@gmail.com', 'Avijit Biswas')
            ->subject('This is Subject');
    });
});
```

I use

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```

But after running the project it is seen

```
Method Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::test does not exist.
```

I have tried a lot to solve this but i didn't get any solution. What can i do?

Comment: Use `Mail::send()` instead of `Mail::test()`.

Comment: did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and its work .thank you sir

Comment: Can you accept my answer please?

Comment: yeah,sure sir :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Mail::send()` instead of `Mail::test()`

Because `send()` is the inbuilt function in `Mail`.